# Need to understand some pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

Well, i have this simple example that we must use in school but i dont understand why we must use pointers and what they exactly do in same cases.

```
   int **create(int lines, int columns)
   {
   int **p, i;
   p = (int **) malloc(lines * sizeof(int *));
   for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
      p[i] = (int *) malloc(columns * sizeof(int));   
   return p; 
   }
```

I google that `**` is pointer to pointer. Simply pointer pointing to pointer that has stored address of variable. But WHY I should do that?
And then these two lines of code looks to have totally random pointers

```
p = (int **) malloc(lines * sizeof(int *));
p[i] = (int *) malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
```

Basically I understand that pointer is pointing to address of variable or something but don't know what is happening here. Please if can somebody explain it to me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Read [modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Your question is actually a difficult one (related to [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of [memory addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address)). I recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) to understand what is a memory location

Comment: The code creates `columns + 1` 1D arrays, mimicking a `lines x columns` sized 2D-array. All those 1D-arrays are separate blocks of memory. The latter kind of construct also sometimes is called a "jagged" or "scattered" array. A real 2D-array would be exactly one block of memory. This `int array2d[5][7]` for example defines a **real** 2D-array.

Comment: And BTW, C does **not** require to cast `void`-pointers. All those cast inside the code you are are needless in C (as opposed to C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer can also be understood as an array. You allocate some space with `malloc`, and you can set items with the `[]` operator, just like as arrays.

```c
int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
arr[1] = 5;
printf("%d", arr[1]); //output is 5
```

Pointers to pointers can be understood as two-dimensional arrays: You allocate space *for the pointers*, then allocate each pointer as an array.

```c
int** arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3); // each element is going to be an array of 3 integers
}
arr[2][2] = 4;
printf("%d", arr[2][2]); // 4
```

Comment: I wouldn't advertise a pointer as an array, although both can be used in a similar fashion.

Comment: I think "can be used as" is more appropriate than "can be understood as". A pointer may just point to a struct instead of starting address of a set of primitives.

Answer (score 1):

This function creates a matrix which is a two dimensional array.

An array is a sequence of elements stored contiguously in memory. With `malloc` we allocate a memory block that can be used as an array. We then hold a pointer to the block of elements. We can then use the notation `a[i]` to identify the ith element of the array whose address is stored in `a`.

The expression `malloc(n * sizeof(int));` allocates a memory block with room for `n` integers. Note that it returns a pointer to an integer : `int *`.

When we create a two dimensional array, each row is an array allocated with the above instruction. `n` is replaced by the number of columns.

All the rows are then bundled together with an array of arrays. Remember that an array is of type `int *`. Thus an array of arrays has `int *` values as element. It's type is then `int **`.

The first `malloc` in your code allocates the array that will hold all the rows array. This is why its type is `int **`. Its byte size is `lines` time the byte size of an `int *`.

In the `for` loop, each row is instantiated and assigned to the corresponding element of the array `p`.

The pleasant thing of the returned two dimensional array is that you may then identify on of its elements by the expression `a[i][j]`.

---

Note that there is a mistake in this code.

The for loop is `for(i = 0; i < riadky; i++)`. `riadky` is an undefined variable. It's not the right variable name.

Now that you hopefully understand the code, could you find the correct variable name to put there ? You should be able to find it from my explanations.

Comment: "*All the rows are then bundled together with an array of arrays*" they most likely are not. What is bundled are pointers to rows' 1st element. The rows themselves are separated block of memory. It cannot be assumed the rows were one continues memory region.

Comment: Technically no array is involved. The first allocation allocates a block of memory to hold the number of requested pointers and the start address for that block is assigned to the first pointer. (you have a block of uninitialized pointers at that point). You initialize each pointer by allocating a bock of memory sufficient to hold whatever object type the pointers will reference and assign the starting address for each block to each of the pointers in sequence. Following allocation, you have a block of pointers and storage for objects assigned to each pointer. You can simulate 2D access

Comment: "*no array is involved*" that's a bit harsh, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Some pictures should help.

We start with the object `p`:

```
   int **
   +–––+
p: |   |
   +–––+
```

`p` has type `int **`, meaning it can store the address of an object of type `int *`.

For simplicity’s sake, we’ll assume both `lines` and `columns` are `2`.  So we start by dynamically allocating enough space for two objects of type `int *`, and store the address of the first of those objects into `p`:

```
   int **        int *
   +–––+         +–––+
p: |   | ––––––> |   |
   +–––+         +–––+
                 |   |
                 +–––+
```

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` *elements* (**not bytes**) from that address<sup>1</sup> and dereference the result<sup>2</sup>.  So the expression `p[0]` refers to the first element and `p[1]` the second:

```
   int **        int *
   +–––+         +–––+
p: |   | ––––––> |   | p[0]
   +–––+         +–––+
                 |   | p[1]
                 +–––+
```

Now, for each `p[i]`, we allocate enough space for 2 `int` objects and assign the address of the first of each set into `p[i]`:

```
   int **        int *          int
   +–––+         +–––+          +–––+
p: |   | ––––––> |   | p[0]-––> |   | p[0][0]
   +–––+         +–––+          +–––+
                 |   | p[1]–+   |   | p[0][1]
                 +–––+      |   +–––+
                            |
                            |   +–––+
                            +-> |   | p[1][0]
                                +–––+
                                |   | p[1][1]
                                +–––+
```

As for why you need to use multiple levels of indirection (`**`, `***`, etc.)...

For any object `E` of type `T`, the *expression* `&E` evaluates to the address of that object, and the type of that expression is `T *` (pointer to `T`).  If we repace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, then the type of `&E` is `P **`.  IOW, the type of an object that holds the address of another object must have one more level of indirection than the pointed-to object.

---

1. Pointer arithmetic works in terms of objects, not bytes.  If `p` has type `int *` and points to an `int` object, then `p+1` points to the next `int` object immediately following, whether that object is 2, 4, or more bytes away.

   ”But everyone says arrays are not pointers, how is `a` an address?”  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type “N-element array of `T`” will be converted (“decay”) to an expression of type “pointer to `T`” and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.